# Unable to start nginx service in docker container (Oracle linux 7)

Tags: linux, docker, oracle-linux

I installed nginx(rh-nginx116-nginx) on Oracle Linux 7 docker image. After launching container, while starting of nginx service, getting following error:-

```
 [root@7b5b3ae7d392 /]# systemctl status rh-nginx116-nginx
● rh-nginx116-nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rh-nginx116-nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2020-10-04 13:19:09 UTC; 11min ago
  Process: 264 ExecStart=/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/libexec/nginx-scl-helper enable $RH_NGINX116_SCLS_ENABLED -- /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 258 ExecStartPre=/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/libexec/nginx-scl-helper enable $RH_NGINX116_SCLS_ENABLED -- /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 251 ExecStartPre=/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/libexec/nginx-scl-helper enable $RH_NGINX116_SCLS_ENABLED -- /usr/bin/scl_enabled rh-nginx116 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 250 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /var/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/run/nginx/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /docker/7b5b3ae7d3922947203ceb8164bd1746c707b0851deb7283cf84f7642564eb54/system.slice/rh-nginx116-nginx.service
           ├─270 nginx: master process /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/sbin/nginx
           ├─271 nginx: worker process
           └─272 nginx: worker process

Oct 04 13:17:39 7b5b3ae7d392 systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Oct 04 13:17:39 7b5b3ae7d392 nginx-scl-helper[258]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx1... ok
Oct 04 13:17:39 7b5b3ae7d392 nginx-scl-helper[258]: nginx: configuration file /etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/n...ful
Oct 04 13:17:39 7b5b3ae7d392 systemd[1]: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acqu....pid
Oct 04 13:17:39 7b5b3ae7d392 systemd[1]: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acqu....pid
Oct 04 13:19:09 7b5b3ae7d392 systemd[1]: rh-nginx116-nginx.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 04 13:19:09 7b5b3ae7d392 systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Oct 04 13:19:09 7b5b3ae7d392 systemd[1]: Unit rh-nginx116-nginx.service entered failed state.
Oct 04 13:19:09 7b5b3ae7d392 systemd[1]: rh-nginx116-nginx.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Nginx Systemd Unit file:-

```
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/run/nginx/nginx.pid
EnvironmentFile=/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/service-environment
# Nginx will fail to start if /run/nginx.pid already exists but has the wrong
# SELinux context. This might happen when running `nginx -t` from the cmdline.
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1268621
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /var/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/run/nginx/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/libexec/nginx-scl-helper enable $RH_NGINX116_SCLS_ENABLED -- /usr/bin/scl_enabled rh-nginx116
ExecStartPre=/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/libexec/nginx-scl-helper enable $RH_NGINX116_SCLS_ENABLED -- /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/libexec/nginx-scl-helper enable $RH_NGINX116_SCLS_ENABLED -- /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=process
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: how does the systemd unit file look for the nginx service?

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your log file: `Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acqu....pid`

Check this [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4410831). As explained, systemd now enforces checking the PID defined in service units before allowing the service to start.

Your nginx service unit is probably not compatible with your systemd version. I suggest you to check that.